# ipset remove just one ip or subset from existing set

Tags: debian, ip, blocking, adblock

I have an ipset where various ip ranges are added.

This ip ranges are loaded automatically from a list of ips and ip ranges for blocking purposes.

I'm trying to remove just one ip or a smaller subset from a subset already added.

If I do

```
ipset test listname IP
```

it says that ip is in set listname

however if I try to remove it with

```
ipset del listname IP
```

it says that the entry is not added in the set

My guess is that I would need to track the ip range previously added because it was clearly a range and not a single ip, remove the range, split it in two ranges around that single ip, remove the original range and add the two ranges back?

How can I know what range were added? do a verbose option of test exists so that I can understand wich was the original specified range were that ip was in?

Shouldn't ipset del do this long job for me already ??? If I want to remove an ip from a range that calculations should be done automatically!

Comment: Perhaps you've hit [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1455732). Try `firewall-cmd --permanent --ipset=listname --remove-entry=IP`.